# Selected Index Change Calling when Filling values in Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In the below code I have a `combobox`. When I try to fill values in `combobox`, on loading it is calling `SelectedIndexChanged` without selecting a value `combobox`.

```
public void BindCombobox()
{    
    Software pd = new Software();
    DataSet dsProj = pd.UserID();
    cbValue.DataSource = dsProj.Tables[0];//Calling SelectedIndexChanged
    cbValue.DisplayMember = "ProjectName";
    cbValue.ValueMember = "ProjectID";
}

private void cbValue_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Could you explain better what is your problem? Yes SelectedIndexChanged will be called when you bind a datasource to your combobox

Comment: @steve  SelectedIndexChanged is called when i bind a datasource to combobox

Comment: Still you don't explain what is the problem. You don't want the event to be called while you bind the datasource? or whatelse?

Comment: Right after you bind, doesn't the ComboBox display the first item?  That would be a SelectedIndexChanged from -1 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must use a boolean variable. it may help you , I used this method to avoid this problem
do something like given below.

1) Declare a boolean valiable with global scope, set it to false.
2) before binding combobox set `boolean=false`, and after binding has been completed set `boolean=true`.
2) now on very first line of `combobox_selectionChangeEvent` , check the condition that the boolean is true or false. if its true then do rest of the things.

like this..

```
boolean flag=false

public void BindCombobox()
{
    Software pd = new Software();
    DataSet dsProj = pd.UserID();
    flag=false;
    cbValue.DataSource = dsProj.Tables[0];//Calling SelectedindexChange
    cbValue.DisplayMember = "ProjectName";
    cbValue.ValueMember = "ProjectID";
    flag=true;
}

private void cbValue_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(flag==true)
    {
        ... //rest of the code
    }
}
```